# Client passwords manager

Tags: password-management

I've been looking around for a good password/domains manager. Something to keep track of my clients passwords, domains, DNS, database access, etc. Web based is a must.

I've heard about KeePass, TrueCrypt, but it's a desktop client, so I'm not interested in that.

**Something open source would be ideal**. With the ability to make extensions to it.

Comment: I must say that sounds very insecure. You could trust something that's fairly secure such as Google Docs with a very strong login password.

Comment: We currently have a really old solution using double login, with htaccess based and then a second really strong password.

Comment: The problem is the web server containing passwords could be compromised in other ways. I've seen a very secure server with SSH keys for other servers compromised which took out the entire network in minutes.

Comment: Those are good points. I think I will have to check KeePass, but I was trying to avoid as much as I could to use desktop apps.

Comment: You did read these questions already right?   Can you update your question with more details since right now they seem to provide many answers already. http://serverfault.com/questions/30080/whats-the-safest-online-password-system http://serverfault.com/questions/21374/how-do-you-manage-your-passwords http://serverfault.com/questions/10285/best-practise-and-solutions-for-sharing-passwords http://serverfault.com/questions/2186/password-manager-that-allows-syncing-accross-platforms

Comment: Most of the questions are based on desktop app solutions. As I mentioned, I'm looking at web based and open source alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at Lastpass. It is web based host proof password manager. Sadly it is not open source or have the ability to add extensions.

https://lastpass.com/enterprise_overview.php

Comment: Thanks! I took a look at LastPass last night and it seems like a good solution. I can avoid all the security hassle by using this.

Answer (score 0):

Closet would be Dropbox with truecrypt portable mode up there and a TC volume with passwordsafe on it.

3 Different complex passwords

http://www.truecrypt.org

http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net